# List of devices attached is empty on Google Colab while packaging kivy app

Tags: android, kivy, google-colaboratory, buildozer, kivymd

I am making a kivy app. I am using google colab to package the app to apk format.
When i install the app on my android phone. It closes immediately after loading screen. I want to debug the app. So i found this command `!buildozer -v android debug deploy run logcat` I am still using google colab, even to debug. But this command needs developer mode and usb debugging on the android phone to be activated, and i have done that already. When i run the command which is `!buildozer -v android debug deploy run logcat`. in the process, the list of devices attached is empty, so i cant debug. How can i do this in google colab?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot run `adb` on google colab! first download the apk from google colab then install it from your windows.
`adb install #path_to_apk`

Comment: ok. will i be able to debug my kivy app using this. if you know please explain how

Answer (score 0):

First download `platform-tools` from https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/platform-tools. Unzip downloaded file and navigate CMD to the folder with name `platform-tools`. Then download your app from google colab and save it somewhere on your drive.Then run `./adb install #path_to_apk` from your cmd for example `./adb install C:\Users\User\Downloads\myFirstApp.apk` . if you are getting error while installing the app. you might need to uninstall it first with `./adb uninstall #package_name` for example `./adb uninstall com.kivy.newapp` . After installing the apk you simply run `./adb logcat` then all debugging information will show up.